# Retrieve an entire row for a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I need to compare a column, called `last_login`, and if the date match with today's date I want to retrieve the whole row to a list, or something similar:

```
def joined_today(self, df):

    users_joined_today = []
    date_joined = pd.DataFrame(df)
    today = datetime.date.today()

    for i in date_joined['last login']:
        i = i.date()
        if i == today:
            users_joined_today.append(i)

    return users_joined_today
```

I am just wondering what can be an efficient way to retrieve the whole row matching with the values returned by `joined_today()` function?

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas, you should aim to use vectorised operations:

```
# convert series to datetime, if not already
df['last_login'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_login'])

# calculate Boolean series mask
mask = df['last_login'].dt.normalize() == pd.to_datetime('today')

# apply mask
df_filtered = df[mask]

# optionally, convert to list of lists
df_filtered_L = df_filtered.values.tolist()
```

Normalizing a `datetime` series flattens the time component to zero, so you can compare it with `pd.to_datetime('today')`, which is already normalized.

For example, `pd.to_datetime('now').normalize() == pd.to_datetime('today')` returns `True`.

Comment: I am not sure if I expressed myself correctly, but how can I retrieve from here the whole row where `df['last_login']` and index `n` matches with?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: what's "index `n`"?

Comment: Let's assume I have this df, that containes x number of rows, i say to pandas to check if today's  date matches with the date in the column named `last_login`, if it matches, how can I retrieve the whole row, and not only `df[last_login]`?

Comment: That's explained in my answer. `df_filtered` is a filtered dataframe consisting of all rows which match your criterion. You don't need a `for` loop.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot, I did not get this